# Passing a Go template format string to an Ansible command

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to query a bunch of Linux servers, to see what version of Docker is installed.

My simple playbook looks like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Query Docker
  any_errors_fatal: false
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Query Docker version - Debian/Ubuntu
      ansible.builtin.command: docker version --format '{{.Server.Version}}'
      become: no
      register: result

    - name: Output Debian/Ubuntu results
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: result
        verbosity: 1
```

Running that docker command on the command line gives me the value I need, for example, something like "20.10.14" or "20.10.7".

When I try passing that command using [ansible.builtin.command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-command-module) module, the templating breaks, with the error message:

```
template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: docker version --format '{{.Server.Version}}'
```

**Note:** I realize I can also get this information by using the [community.docker.docker_host_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_host_info_module.html) module, and that's actually what I am doing to accomplish my task, but I would still like to know how to pass a Go template string, with double curly-brackets, correctly quoted to an Ansible command.

**EDIT:**
This was closed as a duplicate of another question, but I am going to leave it here in case it helps anyone else find the answer to a similar issue.

The fix was to put brackets around the text, like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Query Docker
  any_errors_fatal: false
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Query Docker version - Debian/Ubuntu
      ansible.builtin.command: docker version --format {{'{{.Server.Version}}'}}
      become: no
      register: result

    - name: Output Debian/Ubuntu results
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: result
        verbosity: 1
```

Comment: you have a typo with dot before Server.Version?,  this is what the error says...

Comment: No, it is not a typo. Running that command at a shell prompt gives the Docker version, such as 20.10.14.